# Conservative field application

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to show that

$\int_C \frac{x \text{d}x - y\text{d}y}{x^2+y^2} = 2\pi$?

I tried Green's theorem and Stokes' theorem but ended up with 0.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you fill in some details? What is $C$?

Comment: Are you sure this vector field is conservative?

Answer (score 4):

You can use polar coordinates to parametrize. I assume $C$ is a circle (you can assume radius is $1$), so that you can use the parametrization: $$x=cos\theta , y=sin\theta$$ and $x^2+y^2=1$. Now, substitute in your expression and find the integral.

You end up getting $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac {[(cos\theta) (cos\theta)-(sin\theta)(-sin\theta)]d\theta}{1} $$

EDIT: like someone commented, the value of the integral is constant of the homotopy class
of the curve, so this result for the circle holds if you integrate over any curve homotopic to the circle ( homotopic in  $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Comment: No problem; I edited a little extra.